# Topic limit exceeded error thrown when updating PushTopic

Tags: salesforce, force.com, apex

I can create and update `PushTopics` without issue until the limit is reached. Once the limit is reached, I can't update existing topics, the following error is thrown:

> Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id xxx; first error:
>   LIMIT_EXCEEDED, exceeded the maximum allowed number of push topics: []

```
[note - xxx == Id of the PushTopic]
```

I am not inserting or upserting - just updating the query.

If the org limit is 20 topics, everything works perfectly up until 19 topics. At 20 topics this error is thrown.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is a bug. We will fix and patch it in production soon.

Workaround:

We could only "active" topics towards this limit. So temporarily set isActive=false, update the topic which will succeed now. Reset back isActive flag.

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in the Winter '15 release. Apologies for the delay in rolling out this fix.